# SQL CASE with Multiples WHEN conditions not working

Tags: sql

I have two tables called tblPostCode (State, SALES_AREA), tblDirectSalesArea AS DSA_HK (SALES_AREA) and a View called vwPxPAxWeb (SALES_AREA)

I was trying to get the data with the logic as below

```
IF dbo.tblPostCode.State IS NULL USE vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA,
IF vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA IS ALSO NULL THEN USE DSA_HK.SALES_AREA 

ELSE USE  DSA_HK.SALES_AREA  END END AS SALES_AREA_DESC
```

And the SQL query I used is as below

```
CASE WHEN dbo.tblPostCode.State IS NULL THEN vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA 

WHEN vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA IS  NULL THEN DSA_HK.SALES_AREA ELSE 

DSA_HK.SALES_AREA END END AS SALES_AREA_DESC
```

Here note that the data in table tblDirectSalesArea AS DSA_HK is never  NULL . In the end result,  there should not be any NULLS in the field SALES_AREA_DESC.

But I am not getting the result that I expected as there are NULLS  showing up in the field SALES_AREA_DESC.

Is there any issues with my query??

Comment: You do : "CASE WHEN dbo.tblPostCode.State IS NULL THEN vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA" but if "vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA" is null, you'll get NULL

Answer (score 2):

One of your nested case can be managed with the COALESCE operator.

```
case when dbo.tblPostCode.State IS NULL 
  then coalesce(vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA, DSA_HK.SALES_AREA )
else DSA_HK.SALES_AREA end as SALES_AREA_DESC
```

now, if DSA_HK.SALES_AREA is null, you will get a null anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use `COALESCE` here, like so:

```
SELECT 
CASE
WHEN dbo.tblPostCode.State IS NULL THEN
    CASE
    WHEN vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA IS NULL THEN DSA_HK.SALES_AREA
    ELSE vwPxPaxweb.SALES_AREA
    END
ELSE DSA_HK.SALES_AREA
END
FROM <your_data_source>
```

Note that this is pretty much the same as Raphael's answer. I have only made it slightly more verbose to demonstrate the use of nested `CASE` statements.

`CASE` follows short-circuit logic - it stops evaluation with the first condition that is satisfied. So in your original implementation, evaluation would stop as soon as `dbo.tblPostCode.State` was found to be `NULL`. Therefore, you need to nest the check for the next column in the sequence to do the `NULL` check on it correctly.

Comment: No. You don't wanna return dbo.tblPostCode.State, even if it's not null.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I understand that from the question. Could you please point me to the relevant text in the question?

Comment: Well, in the pseudo algorithm, do you see a `USE dbo.tblPostCode.State`  (where USE is something like `return`)

Comment: I havent tried the second query.but  the first one works perfect.

Comment: @user2380064 Fair enough, although I did test before posting. Like I said, the concept is the same in either, and Raphael's query is more concise so I would recommend using that.